# Why doesn't jslint recognize "window"

Tags: javascript, jslint

even when I select `in the browser`.  I thought every browser used this as the global object.

I have to type it in manually in the globals section to make it go away.

Comment: Because JSLint is a tool for enforcing Douglas Crockford's coding practices, and Crockford doesn't like using "the dreaded global object." So `browser` doesn't predeclare the `window` or `self` globals for you, even though any reasonable interpretation of "assume a browser" would.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the JSLint specification. The exact reason I'm not sure (you'd have to ask the jslint devs). If you use the "assume a browser" option it will add common globals for you but `window` [isn't one of them](http://www.jslint.com/help.html):

> `browser`
>
> `true` if the standard browser globals should be predefined. This option will reject the use of import and export. This option also disallows the file form of the 'use strict' pragma. **It does not supply `self` or `window`; you will have to request these aliases of the dreaded global object yourself.**

*(my emphasis)*

You'll have to add

```
/*global
window, self
*/
```

...to tell JSLint about them.

Comment: I think the reason is partly made here: _"It does not supply self or window; you will have to request these aliases of the **dreaded global object** yourself."_ (emphasis mine).  There are a lot of reasons to prefer jshint to jslint, the attitude of the developers of the latter is one of them...